# Strange localstorage item on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While adding in a `localstorage` function to my web app, I noticed a strange key/value in the chrome console.

```
key: ruulzIndex
value: 1000000000
```

I don't see it on Safari or Firefox, so it's just a chrome "thing".

Initially, I thought it was something popping up from an older or other page on my website but it's on all sites (including Google) and only on Chrome.

Does anyone know what it is? I assume that it's a Google addition for something chrome does, so can be ignored, but I would like to know what it does.

Comment: Most likely from an installed extension. Disable all extensions, close/reopen browser and load the page again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from the Designers Ruler chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/designers-ruler/mlbnpnlmfngmlcmkhjpbfokdphfehhjj?hl=en).

I noticed ruulzIndex in local storage as well. Once I disabled the Designers Ruler extension, no new sites I visited had that item in local storage. Once I deleted the ruulzIndex local storage item from sites that I'd already visited, it didn't come back, unless I enabled the extension again.

It looks like the developer of Designers Ruler needed to make sure the z index of the ruler would always be higher than everything else.

Comment: Just checked and yes, I have that extension.